# Cisco ASA 5510 Static One to One NAT

Tags: networking

I am trying to use Static NAT on Cisco ASA 5510 but only one IP is getting into the network. Can someone please point out my mistake. I have read a lot on Google/Cisco but failed to figure it out. Here is my Configurations;

```
ciscoasa# show running-config
: Saved
:
ASA Version 8.4(5)
!
hostname ciscoasa
names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 shutdown
 nameif ISP1
 security-level 0
 ip address 50.100.150.200 255.255.255.248
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 nameif ISP2
 security-level 0
 ip address 40.80.120.160 255.255.255.240
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.10.10 255.255.252.0
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface Management0/0
 nameif management
 security-level 0
 ip address 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0
 management-only
!
ftp mode passive
clock timezone GMT 0
dns domain-lookup ISP1
dns domain-lookup ISP2
object network ISP1
 subnet 192.168.8.0 255.255.252.0
object network ISP2
 subnet 192.168.8.0 255.255.252.0
object network Server_10.51
 host 192.168.10.51
object network Public_120.161
 host 40.80.120.161
object network Server_10.23
 host 192.168.10.23
object network Public_120.162
 host 40.80.120.162
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any object Server_10.51
access-list outside_access_in extended permit icmp any object Server_10.51 echo
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any object Server_10.23
access-list outside_access_in extended permit icmp any object Server_10.23 echo
no pager
logging enable
logging asdm informational
mtu ISP1 1500
mtu ISP2 1500
mtu inside 1500
mtu management 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
icmp permit 192.168.8.0 255.255.252.0 inside
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
!
object network ISP1
 nat (inside,ISP1) dynamic interface
object network ISP2
 nat (inside,ISP2) dynamic interface
object network Server_10.51
 nat (inside,ISP2) static Public_75.35 dns
object network Server_10.23
 nat (inside,ISP2) static Public_75.36 dns
access-group outside_access_in in interface ISP2
route ISP1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 50.100.150.201 1 track 1
route ISP2 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 40.80.120.161 254
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
http server enable
http 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 management
http 192.168.8.0 255.255.252.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart warmstart
sla monitor 55
 type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho 8.8.8.8 interface ISP1
 num-packets 3
 frequency 10
sla monitor schedule 55 life forever start-time now
!
track 1 rtr 55 reachability
telnet 192.168.8.0 255.255.252.0 inside
telnet timeout 5
ssh 192.168.8.0 255.255.252.0 inside
ssh timeout 5
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0
vpn-addr-assign local reuse-delay 30
dhcpd address 10.10.10.11-10.10.10.254 management
dhcpd enable management
!
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
webvpn
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect skinny
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect sip
  inspect netbios
  inspect tftp
  inspect ip-options
  inspect icmp
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:bbd2c8104910bfa4e9b215125b9cb3f9
: end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your *Dynamic NATs* (see below) are taking precedence over your *Static NATs*

**DYNAMIC NATs**

```
object network ISP1
 nat (inside,ISP1) dynamic interface
object network ISP2
 nat (inside,ISP2) dynamic interface
```

**STATIC NATs**

```
object network Server_10.51
 nat (inside,ISP2) static Public_75.35 dns
object network Server_10.23
 nat (inside,ISP2) static Public_75.36 dns
```

NATs are processed in the order or `Section 1` >> `Section 2` >> `Section 3`.  It is recommended that a **[Section 3 After-auto NAT](https://www.netcraftsmen.com/nat-configuration-on-asa-8-4-part-1/)** is used for the general purpose NAT policy.  More specific NATs should be configured as a **[Section 1 Manual NAT](https://www.netcraftsmen.com/nat-configuration-on-asa-8-4-part-1/)** .

**OTHER NOTES**

- `ip address 50.100.150.200 255.255.255.248` and `ip address 40.80.120.160 255.255.255.240` are bad masks. ASAs do not allow use of a **Subnet ID** to be assigned as an interface address. Other Cisco IOSs allow Subnet ID and Broadcast Addresses to be assigned through the use of the **[ip subnet-zero](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/dynamic-address-allocation-resolution/13711-40.html)** command
- `interface Ethernet0/0` is **shutdown**.  Traffic will not be able to reach any hosts on the 50.100.150.200/29 network.
- `interface Ethernet0/2` is a **/22** network.  I would verify to make sure each of your inside test hosts have a mask of "255.255.252.0" with a valid gateway that matches the interface address of **Ethernet0/2**.
- Your Static NATs only allow the dns service to be translated.  I would remove `dns` from the Static NAT configuration for troubleshooting purposes.

**RECOMMENDED TROUBLESHOOTING COMMANDS**

*Use the debug command with care.*

```
show xlate detail
show nat detail
debug nat 255
```

**ADDITIONAL SUPPORT DOCUMENTS**

[ASA Network Address Translation Configuration Troubleshooting](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/116388-technote-nat-00.html)

[NAT CONFIGURATION ON ASA 8.4+](https://www.netcraftsmen.com/nat-configuration-on-asa-8-4-part-1/)